# How to migrate Opportunity Team Members Records?

Tags: force.com, data-loader, informatica, opportunity-teams

I want to migrate Opty team members using Informatica cloud. I did mapping but when i ran the job it is not updating OpportunityAccessLevel accurately. It updates with Read access although from source there are few records which has OpportunityAccessLevel = Edit. 
So, I don't know what's wrong. 
I also tried inserting OpportunityShare records first then Team Members but that also not working. 
But, if i dump target teammembers into csv and then upload csv using force.com dataloader it updates all the fields accurately.

Can anyone help, how can i fix this to make it work in informatica cloud because that is the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Found the resolution by Modifying API Version to 39.0 in informatica connection.
How did i identify the root cause : 
By seeing the api version in dataloader setting and then veryifying with Informatica SFDC connection setting.